# How to convert String to byte without changing?

Tags: java, android, string

I need a solution to convert String to byte array without changing like this:

Input:

```
 String s="Test";
```

Output:

```
String s="Test";
byte[] b="Test";
```

When I use

```
s.getBytes();
```

then the reply is

```
"[B@428b76b8"
```

but I want the reply to be

```
"Test"
```

Comment: Arrays.toString -- It will array content 't', 'e', 's', 't' (for example)

Comment: See my solution, to convert bytes array to String use new String(bytes, charset)....

Comment: @mahdi, please stop asking same question multiple times, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250271/how-cast-string-to-byte-without-change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always make sure serialization and deserialization are using the same character set, this maps characters to byte sequences and vice versa. By default String.getBytes() and new String(bytes) uses the default character set which could be Locale specific.

Use the getBytes(Charset) overload

```
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Use the new String(bytes, Charset) constructor

```
String andBackAgain = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Also Java 7 added the java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets class, so you don't need to use dodgy String constants anymore

```
byte[] bytes = s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
String andBackAgain = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: I am storing bytes of some json Strings in amazon S3 like this, converting the String to bytes with UTF-8 and back to String the same way you show here, so far I have not got any unexpected result, but im wondering if it is possible to have changes in the String by doing this or I can be safe it will never alter the original content?

Answer (score 0):

You can revert back using

`String originalString = new String(b, "UTF-8");`

That should get you back your original string.  You don't want the bytes printed out directly.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code snippet -

```
String string = "Sample String";

byte[] byteArray = string.getBytes();
```

Comment: warning. this uses the default locale platform encoding, which may result in a/ unexpected behavior and b/ loss of information

Answer (score 0):

In general that's probably not what you want to do, unless you're serializing or transmitting the data.  Also, Java strings are UTF-16 rather than UTF-8, which what more like what you're expecting.  If you really do want/need this then this should work:

```
String str = "Test";
byte[] raw = str.getBytes(new Charset("UTF-8", null));
```