# how do I print the contents of an array of bytes as bytes?

Tags: java, android

I use encrypt(byte) code for input `String` and then save encrypt(String) in DB.

I get `String` encrypt from DB to decrypt it, but I need to cast `String` to `byte` without changing because decrypt get just byte.

I used `s.getBytes();` but it changed it,

I need some code to cast string to byte without changing the String.
Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you mean with `I used s.getBytes(); but it change it`? Can you provide an example what you get and what you expect to get?

Comment: And why you ask the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28244367/how-to-convert-string-to-byte-without-changing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getBytes()` doesn't change the string, it encodes string into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset.

In order to print the array of bytes as a `String` value,

```
 String s = new String(bytes);
```

**Edit:**

it seems as you want to print the string as bytes, for which you can use

```
Arrays.toString(bytes)
```

See this code,

```
String yourString = "This is an example text";
byte[] bytes = yourString.getBytes();
String decryptedString = new String(bytes);
System.out.println("Original String from bytes: " + decryptedString);
System.out.println("String represented as bytes : " + Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

**Output**,

```
Original String from bytes: This is an example text
String represented as bytes : [84, 104, 105, 115, 32, 105, 115, 32, 97, 110, 32, 101, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101, 32, 116, 101, 120, 116]
```

Comment: I want to be byte not string

Comment: you can use `Arrays.toString(bytes)`

Comment: @mahdi, i have updated the answer to print your string as array of bytes.

Comment: @mahdi What you actually want to know is "how do I print the contents of an array of bytes?".